# CheckBox in HeaderTemplate to Select All CheckBoxes in ItemTemplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-3.5

I would like to implement a jQuery client-side script to be able to check/un-check all checkboxes that are in the `<ItemTemplate>` column of a TreeList by clicking in a checkbox located in the `<HeaderTemplate>`. The javascript code that I have doesn't work right now.

```
<telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn HeaderText="" SortExpression="IsSelected" UniqueName="IsSelected">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSelected" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"  ButtonType="ToggleButton" 
            ToggleType="CheckBox" OnCheckedChanged="btnSelected_CheckedChanged" >
        </telerik:RadButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" Text="Select All" onclick="selectAll(this);" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="35px"/>
    <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectAll(CheckBox) {
        TotalChkBx = parseInt('<%= this.rtlRshItems.Items.Count %>');
        var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById('<%= this.rtlRshItems.ClientID %>');
        var TargetChildControl = "btnSelected";
        var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var iCount = 0; iCount < Inputs.length; ++iCount) {
            if (Inputs[iCount].type == 'checkbox' && Inputs[iCount].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0)
                Inputs[iCount].checked = CheckBox.checked;
        }
    }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors on the javascript console when you click the checkbox? I would remove the `TotalChkBx ...` line since it's not really doing anything. Other than that, your code seems correct to me.

Comment: post client side html source not server code if you want this converted

Comment: It looks like the problem is that RadButtons aren't emitted as actual html inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that RadButtons aren't emitted as actual html inputs. According to [this post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/button/how-to-select-deselect-all-radbuttons-as-checkbox-into-a-radgrid-with-javascript.aspx) on the Telerik site, if you require a client-side solution the easiest way to check/uncheck all the RadButtons is to handle the load (OnClientLoad property) client-side event of the button, and populate a global array of buttons. So in your case:

Add this bit of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var buttons = [];
    function ButtonLoad(sender, args)
    {
        Array.add(buttons, sender);
    }

    var checked = true;
    function SelectAll()
    {
        var length = buttons.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].set_checked(checked);
        }
        checked = !checked;
    }
</script>
```

And then add this to your btnSelected:

```
OnClientLoad="ButtonLoad"
```

So it would look like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <telerik:RadButton 
        ID="btnSelected" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="false" 
        ButtonType="ToggleButton" 
        ToggleType="CheckBox" 
        OnClientLoad="ButtonLoad"
        OnCheckedChanged="btnSelected_CheckedChanged">
    </telerik:RadButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I am not sure what you are doing with `OnCheckedChanged="btnSelected_CheckedChanged"` but hopefully this still works.

Answer (score 0):

I do a script with jquery you only must change de id of div for your template tag.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#cabecera :checkbox").click(function(){
                if($("#cabecera :checkbox").is(":checked")){
                    $("#cuerpo :checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
                }
                else{
                    $("#cuerpo :checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cabecera">
            <input type="checkbox" /> Select all
        </div>
        <div id="cuerpo">
            <input type="checkbox" />1
            <input type="checkbox" />2
            <input type="checkbox" />3
            <input type="checkbox" />4
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```